# How can i set function result into c++ MACRO

Tags: c++, macros

i have problem to set in to c++ MACRO singletone function result . 
this is what i have :

the macro

```
#define CCDICT_FOREACH(__dict__, __el__) \
    CCDictElement* pTmp##__dict__##__el__ = NULL; \
    if (__dict__) \
    HASH_ITER(hh, (__dict__)->m_pElements, __el__, pTmp##__dict__##__el__)
```

and this is how i try to set it :

```
CCDictElement* pElement = NULL;
CCDICT_FOREACH(GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary(), pElement)
{
}
```

the method getGemsDictionary() returns me:
 `CCDictionary*,gemsDictionary`;

the compilation error im getting is (on the line of the MACRO):

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

but if i do :

```
CCDictionary* tempDictionary = CCDictionary::create();
tempDictionary = GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary();
CCDICT_FOREACH(tempDictionary , pElement)
{
}
```

every thing is working .
why ?

Comment: You're using [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Also, macros are text substitution. View the post-preprocessor output from your compiler for the first.

Comment: `pTmpGameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()pElement` is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros simply do text replacement.  So when you do this:

```
CCDICT_FOREACH(GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary(), pElement)
```

This line:

```
CCDictElement* pTmp##__dict__##__el__ = NULL; \
```

becomes this:

```
CCDictElement* pTmpGameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()pElement = NULL;
```

Which is utter nonsense.  This, on the other hand:

```
CCDICT_FOREACH(tempDictionary , pElement)
```

translates to this:

```
CCDictElement* pTmptempDictionarypElement = NULL;
```

Which is perfectly okay.